# Login form using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I am simply trying to log in on a popup log in box. I used AJAX to check whether log in is successful or not. If it is successful move to header location otherwise Give an error.
Code look like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#login').click(function () {
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var pass = $("#pass").val();
            var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&pass=' + pass;
            if ($.trim(email).length > 0 && $.trim(pass).length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxlogin.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            $("body").load("index.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                            //or
                            window.location.href = "index.php";
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#login").val('Login')
                            $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and   password. ");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Form:

```
<div class="user_login">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label>Email / Username</label>
        <input type="email" Placeholder="Email-id" name="email" Required="required" id="email"/>
        <br />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" Placeholder="Password" name="pass" Required="required" id="pass"/>
        <br />
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="remember" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="remember">Remember me on this computer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="action_btns">
            <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
            <div class="xyx"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="submitm" id="login"/></div>
            <div id="error"></div> 
        </div>
    </form>
    <a href="#" class="forgot_password">Forgot password?</a>
</div>
```

and php file is separate named as ajaxlogin.php:

```
include('includes/db.php');
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$email' AND BINARY pass=BINARY '$pass'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $email;
    }
}
```

Both Script and form are on same page. Output that i am currently getting is Error message Both for right and wrong Username/Password Match. But if i delete "return false;" from script it moves to header location without log in.

Comment: You need to print something (like print 'ok'; if logged) because you are checking data on Js

Comment: Do you see request being sent in the network tab of browser developer tools?

Comment: Hello Marco, where i should use "print ok" as i don't have knowledge of Ajax..Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: Your are using deprecated features mysql_* and the code is open to sql injection (anyone can drop your database or login as any user)

Comment: @AshishGarg after this $_SESSION['user']=$email; put a print 'ok';

Comment: @ EternalHour No, i don't see any request being sent in the network tab of browser developer tools for this log-in box..

Comment: @marco it worked little bit..As now it gives an error for wrong input but for right username/password match it goes to location header without log in....

Comment: You may need to change a little your sql query @AshishGarg have you tried that on a db management tool like phpMyAdmin? It Works well?

Comment: @RonniSkansing What i need to do then ? Any help is appreciated...

Comment: @AshishGarg As for mysql you can use mysqli_* function or PDO Libraries to use a non deprecated commands :)

Comment: @MarcoMura Yeah its working absolutely fine if i use this code without AJAX to log in.. My form is in a popup window i don't think that it should create any problem...

Comment: try to print your query and see what is generated, then try to launch that query on your db from php my admin and see what it tells you

Comment: @MarcoMura Problem has been resolved what i was doing is starting session at the top of the page....I use another session_start() before login php script and it worked fine for me...Thanks all for your valuable time....

Answer (score 0):

try this script,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('#login').click(function()
    {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var pass = $("#pass").val();
        if ($.trim(email).length > 0 && $.trim(pass).length > 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxlogin.php",
                data: {email:email,pass:pass},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data)
                    {
                        $("body").load("index.php").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);

                        window.location.href = "index.php";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $("#login").val('Login')
                        $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and   password. ");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Hello akhil, facing same problem on your script also.

Comment: OP's taking data and do an ajax, what is the use of action or method? That said, your code will work after he fix the php part to return something, data (if not printed something from php) will always be null

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not returning any data from ajaxlogin.php
so the success function always takes control to else and throws you an error message on the screen.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: They don't have enough rep to make a comment.

Comment: @MarcoMura how i can display a message of successful login for 2-3 seconds in the same popup by hiding login form and then reload my window ? any help...??